# Unable to understand about axios API

Tags: http, post, axios, get

I'm trying to learn about API's through tutorial and isn't making any sense to me.
What can do to build my understanding about the topic?

I tried to follow up with tutorial but because lack of understanding about the topic I gave up right there.

Comment: if you're not understanding textual documentation, try watching some videos on YouTube. :)